# How to fix 'ctags ctrl-t in gvim is not working tab basis'

Tags: vim, ctags, cscope

I work on gvim editor. I use multiple tabs in gvim to open multiple files. I have ctags set up in my code area. I use 'ctrl ]' to jump to definition of a function call in one tab and then 'ctrl t' to return to the function call. Now if I type 'ctrl t' in this tab again then it does not do anything as expected. But in another tab if I by mistake type 'ctrl t' then this tab also jumps to that function call. Since in this second tab I did not use 'ctrl ]' so I expect 'ctrl t' also to not do anything but it is not working as expected. I want 'ctrl ]' and 'ctrl t' to work tab basis. That is one tab should not affect another tab. Can you tell me how can I fix this issue? My gvim version is 8.0.69.

I searched in google about this problem but I did not find this problem mentioned anywhere in any website.

Comment: Do you have different files open in each tab? Or are they the same file?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, different files are opened in each tab. So each tab file is not same, they are different.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> is dictated by the contents of the [`tag-stack`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#tag%2dstack).
You could setup [`autocommands`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_40.txt.html#40%2e3) to save the current tagstack when leaving a tab, and restore (or clear it) on the entered tab. You can check the following documentation on how to implement it:

- To save the current tagstack:  [`:help TabLeave`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#TabLeave) and [`:help gettagstack()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#gettagstack%28%29)
- To restore the tagstack (or clear if no info available) after moving to a new tab: [`:help TabEnter`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#TabEnter), [`:help TabNew`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#TabNew), and [`:help settagstack()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#settagstack%28%29)

Note that the functions to manipulate the tagstack contents are window based, so this would work only if you use a single windows per tabpage. Otherwise you would have to adapt the approach for entering and leaving a window instead: [`:help WinEnter`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#WinEnter), [`:help WinLeave`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#WinLeave), and [`:help WinNew`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#WinNew).